# Passar valor de JSP para Action

Tags: javascript, java

Tenho a seguinte jsp abaixo, nela o usuário escolhe o estado, ao escolher o estado meu javascript mostra em um alert com a informação que quero passar para a Action para seguir as validações e leva o usuário para outra action "localiza-lojas-estado.do", isso está ocorrendo, quando debugo chego a cair na Action que desejo, mas nao consigo de forma alguma levar o valor do sgEstado para a Action "localiza-lojas-estado.do"

```
  <script>
    function mantemEstado(){

        var sgEstado = document.localizarLojasForm["sgEstado"].value;
        alert(sgEstado);
        form.action = "<c:url value="/localiza-lojas-estado.do"/>";
        form.submit();
    }
    </script>

    <div class="fr">

        <div class="caminho-link">
            <a href="#" class="caminho-link-1" target="_blank">Home </a> <font
                face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#007088"
                style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"> >> </font> <a href="#"
                class="caminho-link-2" target="_blank">Localizar Lojas</a>
        </div>

        <div class="slocator-box">
            <html:form action="/localiza-lojas.do" method="post" styleId="cadastroCliente2">

<html:hidden property="sgEstado"/>

                <div class="slocator-estado">
                    <html:select tabindex="2" onkeypress="Enter(this.tabIndex, event)" property="sgEstado" styleClass="w80" value="Digite seu E-mail" onchange="javascript:mantemEstado();"     >
                        <html:options collection="listaEstados" property="sgEstado" labelProperty="sgEstado" />
                    </html:select>
                </div>


                <div class="slocator-cidade">
                    <html:select tabindex="2" onkeypress="Enter(this.tabIndex, event)" property="dsCidade" styleClass="w80">
                        <html:options collection="listaCidades" property="dsCidade" labelProperty="dsCidade"  />
                    </html:select>
                </div>

                <html:hidden property="sgEstado"/>
                <div class="slocator-bairro">
                    <html:select tabindex="2" onkeypress="Enter(this.tabIndex, event)" property="dsBairro" styleClass="w80">
                        <html:options collection="listaBairros" property="dsBairro" labelProperty="dsBairro" />
                    </html:select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Crie um campo hidden no form, na função `mantemEstado()` você atribui o valor de `sgEstado` no hidden.

Comment: criei <html:hidden property="sgEstado"/> dentro do <html:form>, como o atribuo valor?

Comment: `document.getElementById('sgEstado').value = sgEstado;`
esse código vai dentro da função, verifique id do hidden, use a opção exibir código fonte do navegador. O html é gerado pelo struts 1.x ?

Comment: mas não entendi como passo o valor para a action, como que consigo dar um print na minha action do valor que desejo por exemplo? Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: sim, é gerado pelo struts!

Answer (score 1):

Troque isto:

```
<html:hidden property="sgEstado"/>
```

Por isto:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="sgEstado"  id="sgEstado"/>
```

Inclua isto no seu script:

```
document.getElementById('sgEstado').value = sgEstado;
```

Vá na sua classe de Actions e declare isto (com os getters e setters):

```
private String sgEstado;
```

Explicação:

O JavaScript usa o **id** para localizar a tag oculta (hidden) e definir seu valor.
O Struts2 usa o **name** para definir o valor da string (ou seja, o nome da variável e o "name" da tag devem ser idênticos).